# How to solve a quadratic that needs complex numbers?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, quadratics

I've been given a quadratic equation that I know will have complex roots but I can't figure out how to get there.

The equation is

$$x^2 - 2x\cos(\alpha) + 1$$

I put it into the quadratic formula and got

$$\frac{\cos(\alpha) \pm \sqrt{\cos^2(\alpha) - 1}}{x}$$

but I don't know where to go from here.

We've been told the answer is $$\cos(\alpha) \pm i\sin(\alpha)$$ but I don't know why!

Comment: Two things: 1) you're missing the "fundamental trig identity" $sin^2(a) + cos^2(a) = 1$. (2) you don't need the $x$ in the denominator; you need its coefficient, which is $1$

Comment: You misapplied the formula. You shouldn't have the $x$ in the denominator. It's only a $1.$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Recall that $\cos^2\alpha=1-\sin^2\alpha,$ so that $$\cos^2\alpha-1=-\sin^2\alpha.$$ Hopefully you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as
$$\frac{\cos(\alpha) \pm \sqrt{-\sin^2 \alpha} }{\color{red}{1}}$$
$$=\\cos(\alpha) \pm i\sin \alpha$$

Note:

1) $\sin^2x =1-\cos^2x$

2) Correction in quadratic formula